# about when to put articles before nouns

Tags: grammar

It is a translation question and the right answer is

> The women gives cookies to the kid.

I put an extra "the" before cookies and it is marked as a wrong answer. Would anyone care to give a detailed reason as to when to put article?

Unrelated side note: I can't believe after so many years studying English, I am still struggling with these basic questions..

Comment: This would probably be better for our sister site ell.stackexchange.com.

Comment: _The women_ is plural. _Gives_ is singular. Possibly **that** is the reason your answer was marked wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The article needs cookies to refer back to. So if your document had previously established cookies as being there (e.g., the kid asked the woman for some specific cookies), then it would be acceptable for the woman to give *the* cookies to the kid.  If the kid is just hungry, then the woman gives him cookies.